# how does on clear inputted strings from a Scanner in Java?

Tags: java

so I'm trying to make a small text adventure for some practice and I want to simplify things a bit. so I made a class that handles my text outputting and hopefully inputs. it worked the first time I tried to input something, but when I try again the code throws a NoSuchElementException.

here is the printer class
'''

```
package Printer;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class echo {

   public static void print(String x) {

    System.out.print(x);

}

public static String y;

public static String get(String x) {

    Scanner inputx = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    System.out.println(x);

    y = inputx.nextLine();
    
    inputx.close();

    return y;
    
   }
}
```

the part I'm working on

```
package story;

import Printer.echo;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class MainStory {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    
    
    
    echo.print("hello user and welcome to my dungeon \n");

    echo.get("are you willing to go thru 100 floors each more deadlier "

            + "than the next");
    
    
    if(echo.y.equals("yes")) {

        echo.print("well what ya waiting for, lets hurry up and "

                + "pick your first class \n");

        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(500);

        echo.print("wait I'm supposed to give a list, "

                + "hold on give me like 2 seconds to fetch the list off my drive \n");

        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);

        echo.print("ok here it is in its full glory");

        echo.print("List of classes in Project: Ordus");

        echo.print("Tank");

        echo.print("Rogue");

        echo.print("DPS");

        echo.print("each class has a sus set of skills that "

                + "allow it to blossom into a very cool run");

        echo.get("what shall it be \n");
        
        String input = echo.y;
        
        if(input.equals("tank") && echo.y.equals("Tank")) {

            echo.print("your a tank");
            
        }

        if(input.equals("rogue") && echo.y.equals("Rogue")) {

            echo.print("your a Rogue");
            
        }

        if(input.equals("DPS") && echo.y.equals("dps")) {

            echo.print("your a dps");
            
        }
        
        
        
        
        echo.print("this is the end of the story so far");

        echo.print("plese wait for a update in the near future");
        
    }

    else {
        
    }
    
}






}
```

I want to try to clear the string before the user inputs again so I can be rid of the error.

Comment: Don't close your scanners, and don't create a new scanner every time.

Comment: Closing the scanner also closed the input stream. And once System.in is closed, it's almost impossible to reopen. It is much better to just pass the Scanner as a parameter so the same one can be reused.

Comment: Only close resources you also opened. You did not open `System.in`, so dont close it. You are not responsible for managing it, the JVM does it.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It'd be enough to not close the scanner, so just delete the inputx.close() line.